# Анимация нажатия на LinearLayout (нажатие на внутренний элемент)

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Я использую RecycleView и элементом (разметкой для него) выступает LinearLayout.
В нем я использую Ripple для анимации нажатия, однако если нажимать на ImageView, который находится внутри, анимация не появляется. Как сделать так, чтобы анимация появлялась при нажатии на любом месте LinearLayout?

LinearLayout:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:text="Название" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smallDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Столица" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" />

Comment: на imageView есть onClickListener? Если есть, то уберите его, он должен быть только на рутовом лайауте. Если вам нужен отдельный слушатель на imageView - ему так же надо поставить android:background="@drawable/ripple"

Comment: да, спасибо. Все было из-за того, что на imageView был обработчик нажатия